# Proper Accessor for Django Uploaded Files

Tags: python, django, django-forms, http-post

Assuming a Django form like the following...

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    attachment = forms.FileField()
```

I've seen many tutorials which access uploaded Django files with `request.FILES['attachment']`, however I was under the impression that whenever possible you should access `POST`ed data via `form.cleaned_data['attachment']`.

Is there a reason why one would use `request.FILES[]`? Should these objects contain the exact same data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a form in HTML, it has a particular encoding (or method of sending the data to the server). By default, the encoding is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which essentially sends the form details in a single string. However, if you want to upload files to the server, you need to set the encoding to `multipart/form-data` (thats the `enctype="..."` line you'll notice in all tutorials on the subject). This sends the data in multiple parts, one per form field. For an example of how the two encodings appear, [see here](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/form_enctype.html).

When Django encounters the `multipart/form-data` encoding, it splits the received data into two dictionaries: the `request.FILES` dictionary contains any files uploaded, while `request.POST` contains any other form fields. If you are interested, the processing is done by the `MultiPartParser` class in the `django/http/__init__.py` file.

To illustrate how this data is presented back to your code, lets create a simple application. First, lets make a simple form consisting of a character field and a file field:

```
from django import forms

class TestForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    file = forms.FileField()
```

Next, we'll create a simple view to create a form, bind any submitted data to it, and render it through a template:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

from forms import TestForm

def show_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    else:
        form = TestForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render_to_response('show_form.html', context, RequestContext(request))
```

And finally, we'll use the template to display the form and some information about both the request and the form:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Django forms - file test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>

        <h2>Request details</h2>

        <p>
        Request method: {{ request.method }}
        <br />
        POST data: {{ request.POST|default:"No data" }}
        <br />
        FILES data: {{ request.FILES|default:"No data" }}
        </p>

        <h2>Form details</h2>

        <p>
        Cleaned data: {{ form.cleaned_data|default:"No data" }}
        </p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Note that you'll need to enable the [`django.core.context_processors.request`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) context processor in your settings to see the details about the request.

If we then fire up the server and point our browser to the view, we see what we'd expect to see - an empty form, the request mode was GET, and there was no POST, FILES or form data.

Next, enter a name in the character field but don't pick a file to upload. Upon submitting, we get the expected error about the file field being required. Of more interest to us is the information about the request:

---

### Request details

Request method: POST

POST data: <QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'b032358a4dbd71bc3a776c2ef41b09d9'], u'name': [u'Blair'], u'file': [u'']}>

FILES data: No data

### Form details

Cleaned data: No data

---

As there was no file information sent by the browser, Django has put all the form details into the POST dictionary and left the FILES dictionary empty. As the form is invalid, there is no data associated with it.

Now lets try it without a name, but with a file to upload:

---

### Request details

Request method: POST

POST data: <QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'b032358a4dbd71bc3a776c2ef41b09d9'], u'name': [u'']}>

FILES data: <MultiValueDict: {u'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: image.pdf (application/pdf)>]}>

### Form details

Cleaned data: No data

---

Now, the submitted data has been split between the POST and FILES dictionaries. The file can be accessed through `request.FILES['file']`, but not through the forms cleaned data, as the form was invalidated by the lack of a name. As the file I uploaded was small, it is stored in memory; files above a certain size (2.5MB by default) would be stored in a temporary directory, but your code can handle them the same.

Finally, lets try it with values for both fields:

---

### Request details

Request method: POST

POST data: <QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'b032358a4dbd71bc3a776c2ef41b09d9'], u'name': [u'Blair']}>

FILES data: <MultiValueDict: {u'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: image.pdf (application/pdf)>]}>

### Form details

Cleaned data: {'name': u'Blair', 'file': <InMemoryUploadedFile: image.pdf (application/pdf)>}

---

As the data is valid and bound to the form, the file can also be accessed through the `cleaned_data` of the form.

There is a potential benefit through accessing it through `request.FILES`: if the form is invalid, you can still save the file somewhere before asking the user to correct the data. This prevents having to upload the file again (which could be quite costly in terms of time and bandwidth if you are dealing with large files). If you only want to work with small files, it won't make much difference, but it is probably better practice to use `request.FILES`. This is also how the [Django file upload documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/) does it.

Comment: Wow, this is great information! Thanks very much for the effort put into this--would that I could give you a hundred up votes.

Comment: No problem. I hadn't really thought about this before - I just followed the format of the documentation examples previously - so it was interesting to see how it worked.

Comment: @Blair you deserve more votes. That was a really nice explanation. Thanks for that answer 